# How to Create Rollback & Savepoints on Oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, savepoints

Is there any way to Create a save-point and to Rollback on Oracle apex application I have tried several times on Application but several error occurs

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code should be complete; you can't have only `begin` and `savepoint`. Something like this:

```
begin
  savepoint a;
  delete from test;
  rollback to a;
end;
/
```

---

Your code, fixed (you **must** terminate every statement with a semi-colon `;`):

```
begin   
  savepoint a;
  UPDATE emp SET salary = 70000 WHERE ename = 'HUzaifa';
  rollback to a;
end; 
/
```

Comment: semi colon after "rollback to a;"

Comment: `begin
  savepoint a
UPDATE emp
    SET salary = 70000
    WHERE ename = 'HUzaifa'
  rollback to a end; `   Like this ? @Littlefoot  @Koen Lostrie
@littlefoot  It still doesnt work

Comment: You have to terminate statements with a semi-colon. Have a look at my answer which contains your code, fixed.